# Cast Interface to Subinterface to implement a single method in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, interface

I would like to "cast" an instance of an interface MyInterface and to a subinterface MyInterfacePlus that only implements the methods in the subinterface.

I can't seem to find an elegant solution. In the example below, MyInterface and OtherInterface are long established and implemented/used extensively by users. I would like to make no changes to MyInterface and add only a default method to OtherInterface. For all existing implementations of OtherInterface, the `oneExtraMethod` in the result of `getMyInterfacePlus` will do nothing. That is, the method needs to be there to be called, but it should do nothing.

```
public interface MyInterface {
    ...//lots of methods
}
public interface MyInterfacePlus extends MyInterface {
    void oneExtraMethod();
}
public interface OtherInterface {
    MyInterface getMyInterface();

    // ANY ELEGANT WAY TO DO THIS?
    default MyInterfacePlus getMyInterfacePlus() {
        MyInterface mi = getMyInterface();
        return new MyInterfacePlus() {
            @Override
            void oneExtraMethod(){};
            // override all (many) methods `methodX` in MyInterface to return `mi.methodX`
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You have several options: Use a wrapper (delegate all `MyInterface` methods manually), use a Proxy (delegate them using reflection), or use a language that makes this easy. For example in Kotlin you could use `by` to avoid having to explicitly delegate all `MyInterface` methods.

Comment: Adding `oneExtraMethod` as a no-op default method to `MyInterface` would solve all your problems without any (ugly) workarounds.

Comment: @ThomasBehr that's where I'm at, but there are some details I've omitted that make that less than ideal. But It's probably the best solution for most people looking at this question.

Comment: @Jorn by wrapper, do you mean the example I have in the question? Can you link me to a resource or give a bit more details to the Proxy approach so that I can look on my own?

Comment: Yes, your example is basically a wrapper, except you'd probably make an implementation class with a `MyInterface delegate` field. For proxies, you can look at [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html).